# Cook-Torrance Specular BRDF Artifact

Tags: brdf, specular

I am currently experiencing a very obvious artifact that occurs when looking at objects on very grazing angles

Here is a picture of the artifact:
[image: artifact]

I noticed that the issue was coming from my implementation of Cook-Torrance's Specular BRDF.

Here is the equation for the Cook-Torrance Specular BRDF: 
[image: Cook-Torrance Specular BRDF]

More specifically, calculating the denominator is causing the issue:

```
float denominator = 4 * max(dot(viewDir, normal), 0.0) * max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0) + 0.001;  // Prevents any division by zero
```

When I change the calculation of dot(viewDir, normal) to dot(halfway, normal), the artifact disappears:

```
float denominator = 4 * max(dot(halfway, normal), 0.0) * max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0) + 0.001;  // Prevents any division by zero
```

But this equation is no longer correct. I was wondering if anyone knows why my implementation causes these artifacts?

If you want to see my fragment shader you can find the code here:

https://github.com/Ershany/Arcane-Engine/blob/WIP_PBR/Arcane%20Engine%20Core/src/shaders/pbr_model.frag

Thank you!

Comment: I made that post awhile back and was asking for help with my normal mapping code, which I discovered wasn't the issue. I actually located the issue now and I am asking for feedback on why this is occurring.

Comment: It's fine, just update your original question with the new information you found.